# Induction and basic assumptions in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, induction

I am beginning to work through a text in graph theory and have a couple of questions.

1) Can we always assume a graph is nonempty, i.e., if a graph $G$ has order $n$, do we assume $n\in \{1,2,...\}$?

Allowing the empty graph would seem to cause problems with some of the definitions.

2) Mathematical induction seems to be a major proof technique in graph theory.  Let's say we're doing induction on the size $n$ of a graph.  I often have trouble picking out the $n$ for my base case.  Many times if I start at $n=0$ (by (1) should I ever do this?) or $n=1$ the theorem is almost vacuously satisfied, and it feels like I am cheating. Here is an example:

Theorem. Every closed odd walk in a graph contains an odd cycle.

> proof. Induction on length of walk.
>
> Base case: $n=1$ is vacuously satisfied (there is no closed walk of length
>   $1$ since we are assuming our graphs are simple). I feel like this is cheating, so I go 
>   on to the next case.  If $n=3$ then we can easily prove that the walk is a cycle. Now I feel a little better and proceed with the inductive step...
>
> Suppose we have an odd length $n$ walk and the theorem holds for all
>   odd walks of length $<n$. Suppose the walk $v_0,v_1,...,v_n$ begins
>   and ends at $v_{0}=v_{n}$. If no vertices are repeated along the way,
>   we're done. Else, pick the least vertex that is repeated, then pick
>   the max vertex that matches it. Pick the least vertex after this max
>   that is repeated, and then the max vertex that matches it. If we ever
>   get an odd walk in this process, apply the induction hypothesis, and
>   we're done. Otherwise if they are all even, then when we collapse all
>   of these cycles (loops), we get an odd cycle beginning and ending at
>   $v_{0}$ (since an odd number of edges minus a bunch of even numbers is
>   odd).

What is to stop me from using "dumb" base cases?

Comment: You are correct in noticing that the empty graph (graph on zero vertices) is a special case and can provide several headaches.  It can be used as a counter example for several statements (for example euler's formula) and so it is usually ignored.  However, since sanity, page space, and ink are all at a premium you will find most authors do not acknowledge it's existence except maybe in the foreword and choose not to begin each theorem and proposition with "all graphs (except the empty graph)."  You can also avoid it by saying "all graphs on $n\geq 3$ vertices" or whatever lower bound is useful

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks.  Can anyone now answer my question about induction?  What is to stop me from using "dumb" base cases?

Comment: @Mozart Sometimes the inductive step doesn't work if you use a "dumb" base case. For instance, consider this proof that all sheep are black:
1. Base case: one black sheep exists.
2. Given that every set of $n-1$ sheep is black, consider a set of $n$ sheep $\{s_1, \ldots, s_n\}$. If we take the sets $\{s_2, \ldots, s_n\}$ and $\{s_1,\ldots, s_{n-1}\}$ we can see that all elements of our original set are black. QED.
This fails since the inductive step doesn't work for $n=2$. If you can prove the base case $n=2$ instead of $n=1$ instead, this would be avoided.

Comment: The empty graph satisfies Euler's formula. Euler's formula states $V - E + F = 1 + C$, where $C$ is the number of connected components. When $V = E = 0$ (the empty graph), we have $F = 1$ and $C = 0$, satisfying Euler's formula.

Comment: @Alqatrkapa But shouldn't the base case be that the sheep in every set of size 1 are black (which would be equivalent to your conjecture)?

Comment: @Mozart Ah yes you are quite right. The hypothesis and statements should be "all sheep are the same color." My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Alqatrkapa Oh I see, that is a nice example.

Comment: @ml0105 I was referring to the special case for planar connected graphs (which the null graph vacuously satisfies) being that $V-E+F=2$.  It is nice to know though that the more general formulation with the addition of the $C$ term fixes that problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. What text are you using? Doesn't your text **say** that the vertex set is nonempty? If it doesn't, it should; recognizing the "null graph"" (with no vertices) as a graph is a bad idea. (By the way, the term "empty graph" is often used to mean a graph with no **edges**)
2. Your example proof does **not** use mathematical induction in the form "if $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$, and if $P(1)$ holds, then $P(n)$ holds for all $n$. (E.g., how would you prove that a closed walk of length $13$ contains an odd cycle, using **only** the fact that every closed walk of length $11$ contains an odd cycle?) What you are using is the more general form of induction which goes: "if I can prove $P(n)$ assuming that $P(k)$ holds for **all** $k\lt n$, then $P(n)$ holds for all n". This form of induction **does not require a base case**. However, you do need to be careful to make sure that your induction argument works in the smallest cases. E.g., the statement "a closed walk of odd length is either a cycle or else it contains a shorter closed walk" is true even when the given walk is of length $3$, even though no shorter closed walk is possible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the naming scheme comparing null and empty graphs.  If I could edit my above comment I would.  I suppose I made an assumption comparing to the naming scheme for emptyset and had not been corrected before now.

Comment: @JMoravitz Actually the terminology is more confused than I thought. According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_graph) some people call an edgeless graph a "null graph".

Comment: I am using this book http://www.amazon.com/Combinatorics-Graph-Theory-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387797106/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1418941932&sr=8-1&keywords=combinatorics+graph.  It really does not mention nonempty.